# Fourier Transform of $e^{-<x,Ax>}$, $A$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix

Tags: integration, matrices, complex-analysis, fourier-transform, positive-definite

I would like to understand how to fourier transform the function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$,

$f(x):=e^{-\lt x,Ax\gt}$

with $A$ being a positive definite, symmetric matrix.

I understand that $\lt x,Ax\gt$ will end up being something like $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j$ with a couple of summarizable summands due to the symmetry of $A$:

$\frac 1{{(2\pi)}^{\frac 1 n}}\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-(a_{11}x_1^2+a_{22}x_2^2+...+a_{nn}x_n^2+2a_{12}x_1x_2+...+2a_{23}x_2x_3+...+2a_{n,n-1}x_nx_{n-1})}e^{-i \lt t,x\gt}d^nx $

(Is that even correct?..)

But I am having trouble actually calculating the integral, as I can't see anything I already know I could substitute in this, not even for $n=1$.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Let $h(x) = e^{-\pi \|x\|^2}$. (With the $\xi$ normalization) it is its own Fourier transform. Iff $A$ is positive definite then $A =\pi B^\top B$ with $B \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ then $e^{-\langle x,Ax\rangle } = h(B x)$ whose Fourier transform is $|\det(B)|^{-1} h(B^{-\top} \xi)$ (change of variable $y = Bx, dy= d(Bx)=\det(B) dx$ in the Fourier integral)

Comment: (I will look into this further in the morning, too late in the night for me right now, think this will help though, thanks already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the Fourier transform expression if you express everything in the basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Remember that, by the spectral theorem, $A$ can be diagonalized in an orthonormal basis. That means there is a unitary transform $U$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ such that
$$A=U^T\Lambda U$$
And because $A$ is positive definite, $\Lambda$'s diagonal elements are all strictly positive. Also, because $U$ is unitary, for any $t$ and $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $\langle t, x\rangle = \langle Ut, Ux \rangle$.

With that, the Fourier transform of $f$ now becomes
$$\begin{split}
\hat{f}(t) &=
\frac 1{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-\lt Ux, \Lambda Ux \gt}e^{-i \lt Ut,Ux\gt}d^nx\\
\end{split}$$
By changing the variable $y=Ux$, we get
$$\begin{split}
\hat{f}(t) &=
\frac 1{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-\lt y, \Lambda y \gt}e^{-i \lt Ut,y\gt}|\det U|d^nx\\
\end{split}$$
Noting that $|\det U|=1$ and $U^TU=I$
$$\hat{f}(U^Tt)=\frac 1{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-\lt y, \Lambda y \gt}e^{-i \lt t,y\gt}d^ny$$
If $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ denote the diagonal elements of $\Lambda $ (all strictly positive),
$$\hat{f}(U^Tt)=\frac 1{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \prod_{k=1}^ne^{-\lambda_ky_k^2}e^{-i t_ky_k}d^ny=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-\lambda_ky_k^2}e^{-i t_ky_k}dy_k$$
In other words, if you rotate the axes to align with the eigenvectors of $A$, the $n$-dimensional Fourier transform is the product of $1$-dimensional Fourier transforms of the univariate Gaussian function. And you know the expression for the Fourier transform of a $1$-dimensional Gaussian function.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense now.